# Dart/Flutter: Dependency Handling with different versions. Will there be version conflicts?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, version, conflict

Dart/Flutter

Imagine:

There is Package A, Package B and Package C.
Package A has a dependency on Package B.
Package B has a dev_dependency on Package C with a fixed version of it.

Now imagine Package A would also have a dependency (or even dev_dependency) on Package C but with a different fixed version. Running Flutter pub get for Package A doesn't complain as Package C is hidden in the dev_dependency section of Package B.

But will there be any kind of errors or runtime errors with this constellation? Which version of Package C will then be used?

Cheers,
oga

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in Dart here: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning

If you are using fixed version numbers, then the package versions need to exactly match, you cannot have 2 copies of the same package with different version numbers.

This will be checked when you execute the `dart pub get` command and if any version mismatch is found, the tool will tell you. This happens at build time so way before runtime.

The Dart approach is to rather use version constraints so that a matching version of package C can be found that would match the range constraints of package A and B.